# Calculating vertex potentials from optimal matchings

Tags: linear-programming, duality, matching-theory

> **Question:**
>
> can the solution to the dual of a Linear Program be calculated directly from the solution of the primal Linear Program?
>
> If yes, what are known algorithms and their bounds on complexity.

As an example take the linear assignment problem:
how can $\lambda_i$ and $\beta_j$ be calculated from the $x_{ij}$ of the optimal solution to the primal problem and the cost matrix $\boldsymbol{C}$ if it the primal solution is given and it is not viable to set up the dual problem and solve that.

$$
\begin{align} \text{maximize } & \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i + \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i \\
& \lambda_i + \beta_j \leq c_{ij}
\end{align}
$$

where the primal problem is

$$
\begin{align}
\text{minimize } & \sum\limits_{i=i}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n c_{ij}x_{ij} \\
&\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij} = 1\; \forall j \\
&\sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij} = 1\; \forall i \\
&x_{i,j} ~\in (0,1)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you can. A useful optimality condition is *complementary slackness*, which states that for each constraint either the slack variable or the dual variable is $0$. In particular, for the linear assignment problem this means that $x_{ij}>0$ implies $\lambda_i+\beta_j=c_{ij}$.

Comment: Unfortunately these potentials are not made available by library functions for assignment or matching problems.
The solution shows however that the $\lambda_i$ and $\beta_j$ are not independent for matching edges.